# h5py: how save a scalar attribute as array with shape=(1,)

Tags: python, h5py

I have some data that I need to write into an HDF5 file which will be read by a data processing application.
This I do with [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/).
However, the data processing application seems to only accept attributes with an array size of one, but when I create my attributes with h5py I get an array size named scalar. Below picture is from [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/).

[image]

I understand that when I call `dataset.attrs.create(key, value)` that I can set a dtype and shape [h5py documentation for attributes](https://docs.h5py.org/en/3.2.1/high/attr.html#h5py.AttributeManager.create). But I do not understand what I need to provide to always have the array size as 1 and not scalar. In particular when as shown above, some of them seem to just be set to one out of the box.

I create the attributes in the following way:

```py
import h5py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    out_file = h5py.File('tmp.h5')
    data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    attributes = {'sample': 1, 'option': 'tmp'}

    out_file.create_dataset('tmp_dataset', data=data)
    for attr_key, attr_value in attributes.items():
        out_file['tmp_dataset'].attrs.create(attr_key, attr_value)
    out_file.close()
```

I have tried to specify the dtype to `float` and so on. But it did not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution to this issue.

I had not caught that it was the shape parameter to create I would use for this. So by chaing the MRE from above to:

```py
import h5py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    out_file = h5py.File('tmp.h5')
    data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    attributes = {'sample': 1, 'option': 'tmp'}

    out_file.create_dataset('tmp_dataset', data=data)
    for attr_key, attr_value in attributes.items():
        out_file['tmp_dataset'].attrs.create(name=attr_key, data=attr_value, shape=(1,))
    out_file.close()
```

I have solved the issue

Comment: You an simply write `out_file['tmp_dataset'].attrs[attr_key] = (attr_value, )`. Assigning any sequence such as a tuple, list, or `np.array` with one element should work

Comment: oh cool thanks :D